# How to serve fonts from different servers for IE users?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, conditional-comments

I have users on IE9 who cannot see my custom fonts. First I thought it was a CORS issue, but after some experimentation I believe it is because the security settings are such that IE will not allow any third-party content under any circumstance (this is on a massive conservative enterprise network of managed computers).

This might also be an issue on newer versions of IE set to "high" security, I'm not sure.

So I think the best solution is to serve fonts directly from my domain for IE users, instead of from the CDN.

1. does this sound like a good approach?
2. how can I do this with conditional comments?

Comment: Are you saying you want IE users to get their fonts from a different domain than users with other browsers? Why?

Comment: yes. because IE in "high"-security mode doesn't allow getting fonts from a third-party domain (my CDN) even with CORS set up (as far as I can tell). So for IE users I don't want to use my CDN, I want to serve fonts directly from my main domain.

Comment: I meant, the simplest solution is to serve up the fonts from your main domain to all browsers, including non-IE ones. So why differentiate?

Comment: Because I want to take advantage of the CDN for the other users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to do it with conditional comments. I don't know how your fonts and other styles are organized, but you'll probably want to use

```
<!--[if IE 9]>
    stylesheet using internally served fonts
<![endif]-->
```

and maybe

```
<!--[if !IE]> -->
    stylesheet using CDN
<!-- <![endif]-->
```

The latter will apply not only to non-IE browsers but also to IE10 and up, but you might only need to use the former.

To answer your first question, I prefer using fonts from my own servers when in production. Cuts down on the number of moving parts and means that my site doesn't rely on another site.

Comment: Thanks! I hacked out the Bourbon part of my question and made it its own question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25435024/ie-conditional-comments-with-sass-and-bourbon

Comment: If you put the conditional IE9 comment after the normal stylesheet, you wouldn't need any conditional comments around the normal sheet. The IE9 include would override the previous styles as long as they have the same selector or specificity.