# IE conditional comments with Sass and Bourbon

Tags: css, sass, conditional-comments, bourbon

I want to serve different fonts to different browsers (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25296480)).

Is there a slick way to do this with Sass/Bourbon?

Here's what I have so far:

```
<!--[if IE]> -->
@include font-face("myicons", "myicons", $weight: normal, $style: normal,
                   $asset-pipeline: false);
<![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]> -->
@include font-face("myicons", "myicons", $weight: normal, $style: normal,
                   $asset-pipeline: true);
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: You cannot include IE conditional comments directly inside of a stylesheet. Your best bet is probably to use SASS to compile a different stylesheet for IE, then load it in your HTML using conditional comments.

Comment: Don't forget it is [deprecated for IE10+](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh801214(v=vs.85).aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem it's outside the sass scope, because is just a pre processor, and doesn't have a clue about the browser.
Also is outside css scope deciding conditions for different browsers.

You could do this adding a ie8 class to the html like html5 boilerplate does and then use a css rule to activate the font.

```
body {
  @include font-face("myicons", "myicons", $weight: normal, $style: normal, $asset-pipeline: false);

  .ie8 & {
    @include font-face("myicons", "myicons", $weight: normal, $style: normal, $asset-pipeline: true);
  }
}
```

and in html file

```
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html>         <!--<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Would this work for IE10+? If I'm correct, the HTML file would need an additional line: `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE9">` for IE10+ to behave like IE9 so the IE conditional comments work.

Comment: You are correct, IE10 has disabled by default conditionals http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html