# Serving only font assets directly from app server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass

In my rails app I am serving all my assets through a CDN. I'd like to serve only my fonts directly from my app server. font_url/font-url will always include the the cdn url. Is there any convenient way to generate the path to the font (with digest) without the CDN domain or the protocol (http[s]) included?

The only thing I can think of is writing my own method that replicates the functionality of `asset_path` -- hopefully there is a more elegant way to achieve this.

**update -- backgroun**

I want to serve fonts from my main domain only to IE users so they don't break when in "high security" mode.

- [How to serve fonts from different servers for IE users?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25296480)
- [IE conditional comments with Sass and Bourbon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25435024)

Comment: why not use font-url as i mentioned in your another question?

Comment: because font-url will generate a url with the CDN domain (https://mycdn.com/fonts/font-a1b2c3.ttf) but what I want is the path without a domain (/fonts/font-a1b2c3.ttf)

Comment: I do not understand that sentence, could you clarify?

Comment: Rail precompiles all of your assets into a single file(all your js in a single file, all css in a separate css file). In production, rails inserts an MD5 fingerprint into each filename so if you'll use font-url or image-url or any asset helper it will automatically make proper paths for your assets with that MD5 fingerprint. If your fonts are present in your app/assets/fonts then you can use font-url helper to make proper paths for it

Comment: @Mandeep I am using "url" and "path" to mean different things, it seems you are considering them the same thing. I've updated my question to be more clear.

Comment: Why use the asset pipeline for this at all? Just put your fonts in `public`

Comment: Use `font_path` instead of `font_url`.

Comment: they both return the same value

Comment: @meagar that is perhaps a good point. although to do that i will have to keep two copies of the fonts. i can make some custom code in the precompilation phase that copies the fonts into public. hmmmm

Comment: @JohnBachir Err, no, I mean, *put them in public*. Stop using the asset pipeline for files you don't want served by the asset pipeline. There is no need to put them in `app/assets`, just put the one and only copy in `/public`.

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**

1. Copy the font files into a separate folder, say "ie-high-security" for example. This is to identify them in step #2.
2. Serve files in the folder ("ie-high-security" in the example) by configuring the [`asset_host`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetUrlHelper.html) in "config/application.rb":

   ```
   ActionController::Base.asset_host = Proc.new { |source|
    if source.include?('/ie-high-security/')
      ""
    else
      "http://assets.example.com"
     end
   }
   ```
3. Reference the fonts in the "ie-high-security" folder in a separate stylesheet intended only for IE9.
4. Serve the IE9 stylesheet with conditional comments as suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/a/25415002/368697:

   ```
   <!--[if IE 9]>
     stylesheet using internally served fonts
   <![endif]-->
   ```

**Old suggestion:**

Use `font_path` instead of `font_url`. The first method generates an absolute path without the asset host prepended.

If the font is being included from a stylesheet that is served from your CDN, you'll need a full path back to the app server though.

Comment: "The first method generates an absolute path without the asset host prepended" — this is actually not true "If the font is being included from a stylesheet that is served from your CDN, you'll need a full path back to the app server though." -- you're right! :facepalm: -- but still, I can manually construc this

Comment: i like where you are going with this, but i want a solution that doesn't require me to copy files. i'm going to try a few things and get back to you.